# REST API method doesn't work with json format. [Java]

Tags: java, json, rest, web

I am trying to test a REST API method in postman. The idea is that when I test it using `x-wwww-form-urlencoded`, I get the correct result, but when trying with `Json` format I get status `500 - "Internal Server Error"`.

This is the `POST` method that I am trying to test:

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/send", produces = {"application/json"}, consumes = {"application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "application/json"})
    public void sendFeedback(UserDTORegister userDTORegister,
                             BindingResult bindingResult){
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            throw new ValidationException("Feedback is not valid");
        }
        // create a mail sender
        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        mailSender.setHost(this.emailConfig.getHost());
        mailSender.setPort(this.emailConfig.getPort());
        mailSender.setUsername(this.emailConfig.getUsername());
        mailSender.setPassword(this.emailConfig.getPassword());

        // create an email instance
        SimpleMailMessage mailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();
        mailMessage.setFrom("HopMenu@gmail.com");
        mailMessage.setTo(userDTORegister.getEmail());
        mailMessage.setSubject("New account created - Hop Menu");
        mailMessage.setText(
                        "New account created. Welcome to Hop Menu! Credentials ->" +
                        " email: " + userDTORegister.getEmail() +
                        " pass: " + userDTORegister.getPassword());

        // Send mail
        mailSender.send(mailMessage);

    }
```

I would really appreciate if you could help me. Below are the images for my tests, using `json` or `x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Using x-www-form-urlencoded:
[image: Using x-www-form-urlencoded]

Using Json:
[image: Using Json]

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, using @RequestBody before my `UserDTORegister` param. It seems that you have to use @RequestBody when working with Json format.